# I have HTML page stored in javascript variable how to show it in the page

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, database

This is my variable have HTML code fetched from database, for example:

```
  const z = 
    "<section class="vh-100" style="background-color: #5f59f7;">
    <div class="container py-5 h-100">
      <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
        <div class="col col-xl-10">
          <div class="card mb-5" style="border-radius: 15px;">
            <div class="card-body p-4">
              <h3 class="mb-3">Program Title</h3>"
```

I need to show it as a navbar in my page not as a code. How to show this in my page?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

HTML

```
<div id='output'></div>
```

JS

```
const z = '<p>hello</p><input /><p>goodbye</p>'
document.querySelector('#output').innerHTML = z
```

View it live here on [codepen](https://codepen.io/jspoh/pen/bGKbwNR)

Comment: It will be text printed in screen not like this ->  <p>hello</p><input /><p>goodbye</p>
But I want to be like this => hello goodbye

Comment: ..yes the output will be 'hello goodbye' without the html tags. did you view the codepen output?

I see that you've updated your post with the html elements. do note that your section and div tags were never closed.